# CI-Bonfire Nested LIKE query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, bonfire

I could need a little help in nesting a like query.
My goal is to accomplish something like followed:

```
Select * from 'Library_Book'

WHERE(
    ('BookName' LIKE '%FILTER1%' OR 'BookDescription' LIKE '%FILTER1%')
AND 
    ('BookName' LIKE '%FILTER2%' OR 'BookDescription' LIKE '%FILTER2%')
)
```

My approach until now is:

```
$this->db->select('Library_Book.*');
foreach($filter as $fltr){
    $this->db->like('Library_Book.BookName', $fltr);
    $this->db->or_like('Library_Book.BookDescription', $fltr);
}
$records = $this->find_all();
```

This results in:

```
Select * from 'Library_Book'

WHERE(
    'BookName' LIKE '%FILTER1%' OR 'BookDescription' LIKE '%FILTER1%'
AND 
    'BookName' LIKE '%FILTER2%' OR 'BookDescription' LIKE '%FILTER2%'
)
```

How can I get the brackets around my or_like statements?

Thanks

tutschdamoon

#

CI-BONFIRE ver 0.7

modules/mymodul/models/mymodel_model.php

Comment: lonnieezell pointed out the solution to me.

Comment: $wheres = array();
    foreach ($filter as $fltr)
    {
        $wheres[] = "('BookName' LIKE '%{$fltr}%'' OR 'BookDescription' LIKE '%{$fltr}%')";
    }
 
    $this->db->where( implode(' AND ', $wheres), null, false);
    $records = $this->find_all();

Comment: How can I solve my own question? Or better, how can I post the solution here? Solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as told by lonnieezell from Bonfire.

I tested it and it works.

```
$wheres = array();
foreach ($filter as $fltr)
{
    $wheres[] = "('BookName' LIKE '%{$fltr}%'' OR 'BookDescription' LIKE '%{$fltr}%')";
}

$this->db->where( implode(' AND ', $wheres), null, false);
$records = $this->find_all();
```